# Jasmine unit-tests not started on travis

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, jasmine, phantomjs, travis-ci

I want to make continuous integration for my chrome extension.
Using tools: [GitHub](https://github.com/), [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/), [Bower](http://bower.io/), [components-jasmine](https://github.com/ericlemerdy/components-jasmine).
In *.travis.yml*:

- install *bower*
- in *bower* download *jasmine*
- change default *SpecRunner.html* on my *SpecRunner.html*, which contains my src and  specs
- load my *SpecRunner.html* in [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

*.travis.yml*:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.10"
install:
  - npm install -g bower
  - bower install
  - cd $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR
script:
  - mv -f ./test/SpecRunner.html ./vendor/components-jasmine
  - phantomjs ./test/runTests.js
```

*runTests.js*:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('../vendor/components-jasmine/SpecRunner.html', function(){
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Tests should be failed, but status on travis - **passed**.
Why my tests don't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results of tests is showing on the same *SpecRunner.html*.

For getting results need to print this loaded page.
If *html* loaded in *phantomjs* locally, then url should to follow classic Url/Uri rules, especially for a local file (that's why page not loaded):

```
file:///c:/path/to/the%20file.txt #win
file:///etc/fstab #unix
```

For getting results of tests need parse logs in *after_script* in *.travis.yml* and return value - 0 if tests passed or non-null if tests failed.

Also, probably, it's possible with help itself jasmine (but i'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `after_script: echo $?` to `.travis.yml` to see what is the return value of your test. If it's `0` then Travis behavior is correct.

I merely guess that your test just return 0 regardless of a result. According to [the documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open-url.html) this code just tries to open the file and calls a callback on failure - since there is no not-0-exit callback whole scripts exits normally and build passes.

EDIT:

From what you wrote I understand that Travis runs just fine, and it's `phantomjs ./test/runTests.js` that isn't returning non 0 value. Try to change:

```
function(){
  phantom.exit();
}
```

into something like:

```
function(status){
  if (status === 'success')
    phantom.exit(0);
  else
    phantom.exit(-1);
}
```

And say it that fail the build (I assume that page opening always fails).

Comment: i tryed to add `echo $?` to `.travis.yml`, but it's return 0: `travis_fold:start:after_script
$ echo $?
0`. Also i tryed print `document.body` in callback, it's return empty page

Comment: Travis is correctly passing your build - script command you passed is always returning 0. Say if that change I suggested helped.

Comment: I haven't status, because i'm load locally `html`